# FPS character full body or Hands Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making an First Person Shooter game using unity 3D, which will be multiplayer in future. So i want to use a full body for my FPS.

I am getting problem in placing camera for my FPS body. When i use only hands it works great.

Can any one tell which approach i should use for this . 
1. Should i use two camera one form showing only hands and player weapon and one for showing the rest of view.
2. OR any other way.

I am using unity3d engine for my game development

Answer (score 1):

Just draw the hands because unless your game allows you to look down and see your feet, a whole body approach might be a bit of a waste on computer resources.

Comment: @Bora When rendering the player from their point of view you just draw the hands.  However when the other computer renders you, your app renders the whole body and vice versa. In other words, always render characters as _full body_ **except** when the character is the _local_ player in which case just draw _hands_.

Comment: I am using the same approach. here drawing hands only for local player and full body for other computer, now i am having problem in placing camera for body.

Comment: @Bora OK but if that's the case, when do you actually need a camera for full body mode? I'm confused :P